# changing images in picturebox of windows form using c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to change images in the picture box of windows form according to some conditions.But some how it is not showing any picture.

i placed a black picturebox control in the form and trying to give the path using c# like this...

```
    public void ApplyImage(string strParam)
    {
        if (strParam == "Exit")
        {
            PB.Image = Daemon.Properties.Resources.Exit;
        }
        if (strParam == "Lock")
        {
            PB.Image = Daemon.Properties.Resources.Lock;
        }
    }
```

am i missing something ???

Comment: @karthik : Apart from your question, you should use either switch or if else ladder in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you set breakbpoints on the `PB.Image == bits` of code?  to verify they are actually being hit?

Bear in mind that a stright string comparison (`variable == "Test"`) is case sensitive, a better way of comparing the strings would be:

```
if ( String.Compare(variable, "Test", True) == 0 ) { ... }
```

Comment: I debugged the code, and it is executing properly. But some how not working that way..

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code.

Now you should check following.

- 1) Image Exists and accessible
- 2) Make sure **SizeMode** of Picturebox is set to property like StretchImage.

Comment: @Mahin, the image is accessible when i directly gave the path of image in picture box properties.

sizemode was normal and then i changed to stretchimage, but no luck.

Comment: @Karthik : can you do one thing. Put a new Picturebox on your form. In the properties of picturebox assign this value Daemon.Properties.Resources.Exit to Image property at design time. I just want to make sure that the resources path you are using is ok.

Comment: @Mahin, i tried that already. It is showing the image perfectly. There is no problem in reference to the image path.